# XE4 Firemonkey on iOS prevent sleep mode

Tags: ios, delphi, sleep, firemonkey, delphi-xe4

I am developing an app in Firemonkey XE4 for iOS and need to prevent the device from sleeping when there is no user input. I have found this command for xcode development:

[application setIdleTimerDisabled:YES];

I presume there is an equivalent in FMX?

Can anyone help please?

Thanks

Darryl

Answer (score 7):

You can go straight to UIApplication, as so:

```
uses
  iOSapi.UIKit;

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm6.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  UIApp : UIApplication;
begin
  UIApp := TUIApplication.Wrap(TUIApplication.OCClass.sharedApplication);
  UIApp.setIdleTimerDisabled(True);
end;
```

Comment: Is there a way to do the same with Android??

Comment: it works fine also on Delphi 11