# How can I prevent apps from going into sleep mode in Delphi XE8

Tags: delphi, mobile, firemonkey, delphi-xe8, sleep-mode

I have a multi device Firemonkey project in Delphi XE8 which I use to make iOS and Android apps. If I am running my apps on the devices they sometimes go to sleep if I didn't touch the screen but the app is still loading stuff.

So how can I stop the app from going into sleep mode for both Android and iOS?

Comment: [XE4 Firemonkey on iOS prevent sleep mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16526110/xe4-firemonkey-on-ios-prevent-sleep-mode) and [Delphi XE5 Android. How to use PowerManager.WakeLock?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19021647/576719).

Comment: @LURD, thanks I already found the solution for iOS. I was hoping for a universal solution though.

Comment: Can provide clues on how you accomplished this for iOS ?

Comment: @lowrider you can try the link of LURD. I'm stil trying to find a universal solution for both Android and iOS.

Comment: @LURD if you post your comment as an answer I will accept it! I think there is no universal way to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no universal way to prevent a mobile FireMonkey application from going to sleep when user activity is too low.

For iOS there is one proposed solution here:
[XE4 Firemonkey on iOS prevent sleep mode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16526110/576719) and for Android is another one: [Delphi XE5 Android. How to use PowerManager.WakeLock?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19021647/576719).

They are using different API calls and methods, so it would  be difficult to share the same code. You could wrap the functionality into a library and with some ifdef's perhaps invoke it the same way.